# Python run out of memory because of large no. of possible combinations

Tags: python-3.x

I use python itertools.permutations to generate a permutations of a certain list of content. When I try to store it in a list, I run out of memory because of the large number of possibilities.  I tried to store it in a text file, but I need to recall these permutations at my code later to  choose one of the possibilities which should be in a data type of a list. Can you please help me find a way to recall the saved list so I can access the saved permutations  as a list not as a string. Thank you

```py
from itertools import permutations

text_file = open("comb3.txt", "w")
action_list = [] 
UEs = [[4,5,6],[1,2,3]]
List_UE = [list(p) for p in product(*UEs)]
comb = permutations(List_UE, int(3))
for i in comb:            
    unique_elements, counts= np.unique(list(i), return_counts=True)
    if all(counts == 1):
        text_file.write("{},".format(list(i)))
        action_list.append(list(i)) 


with open("comb3.txt") as file:
    content = file.readlines()
    print([content])
```

Here I access the content as a string; I want it as a list

After I used the suggested code below, I got the following error when I was trying to access the list

```
    File "/projappl/project_2006417/Journal_MEC_UseCase_26_08_2023/envs/mecsch_v2.py", line 519, in _NOMA_action_set_Red_access
action_list = ast.literal_eval(f'[{content}]')
File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/ast.py", line 62, in literal_eval
node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/ast.py", line 50, in parse
return compile(source, filename, mode, flags
```

can anyone suggest a solution, please ?

Comment: Please upload a compilable code. You are missing imports

Comment: Even with the imports print([content]) is an empty list

Comment: you forgot to close the file. See my answer

Comment: If your GOAL here is just to choose one permutation at random from a large universe, there are ways to do that directly, without actually generating the entire result set.  Is that what you want?

Comment: @TimRoberts No I want to access some specific permutations later from the list not random.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying.  You can write a function that says "give me the 393rd permutation from this input" without having to generate 392 permutations first. That's directly computable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this questions we find two problems. First how to read, write to files and python serialize it and second the optimization problem (run out of memory). Please note that your code does not compile, you do not have the right imports and you are forgetting to close the file when writing to it. So you cannot read it in the same script. Please open files using context managers ("with" command in python) so you don't forget to close it. Before you read it use:

```
text_file.close()
```

Now, you can write objects as bytes as  @Jiu_Zou indicated above. Like that you write it directly as byte code and all the serialization heavy work relies on pickle package. It is probably more efficient. However, That answer might not tackle the out of memory issue since you need to keep the full in memory to write it.

Let me show you other way to write and read a python object, you could write it as a string as you where doing it, then read it as a string and serialize it as a tring using

```
ast.literal_eval
```

After the for loop you can do:

```
text_file.close()
with open("comb3.txt", 'r') as file:
    content = file.read()
    content.removesuffix(",")
    data_list = ast.literal_eval(f'[{content}]')
    print(data_list)
    print(type(data_list))
```

Note that I removed the last ",". You don't have to do this. ast.literal_eval interpretates already the string as a list. But just notice that you are storing it with a final ",".

Lastly, you said that you run out of memory. Don't store the full of the permutations list in an array. Keep it in lines and read it in lines, in that way you will only keep the memory of one line once at a time.

```
import ast
from itertools import permutations, product
import numpy as np

with open("comb3.txt", "w") as f:
    action_list = []
    UEs = [[4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3]]
    List_UE = [list(p) for p in product(*UEs)]
    comb = permutations(List_UE, int(3))
    for i in comb:
        unique_elements, counts = np.unique(list(i), return_counts=True)
        if all(counts == 1):
            f.write("{}\n".format(list(i)))
            action_list.append(list(i))

with open("comb3.txt", 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        data_list = ast.literal_eval(f'{line}')
        # do your operations to fetch right permutation here
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It solved my memory problem.

Comment: I got this error when I call the txt file. I cannot understand why action_list = ast.literal_eval(f'[{content}]')
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/ast.py", line 62, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/ast.py", line 50, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, flags,
  File "<unknown>", line 1

Answer (score -1):

you should use pickle to save or load the list type instead of txt file.

```
from itertools import permutations
import numpy as np
from itertools import product
import pickle

action_list = [] 
UEs = [[4,5,6],[1,2,3]]
List_UE = [list(p) for p in product(*UEs)]
comb = permutations(List_UE, int(3))
result = []
for i in comb:            
    unique_elements, counts= np.unique(list(i), return_counts=True)
    if all(counts == 1):
        result.append(list(i))

with open('com.pkl', 'wb') as obj:
    pickle.dump(result, obj)

with open("com.pkl", 'rb') as file:
    ret = pickle.load(file)
    k = 0
    
ret
```

the result look like this

```
[[[4, 1], [5, 2], [6, 3]],
 [[4, 1], [5, 3], [6, 2]],
 [[4, 1], [6, 2], [5, 3]],
 [[4, 1], [6, 3], [5, 2]],
 [[4, 2], [5, 1], [6, 3]],
 [[4, 2], [5, 3], [6, 1]],
 [[4, 2], [6, 1], [5, 3]],
 [[4, 2], [6, 3], [5, 1]],
 [[4, 3], [5, 1], [6, 2]],
 [[4, 3], [5, 2], [6, 1]],
 [[4, 3], [6, 1], [5, 2]],
 [[4, 3], [6, 2], [5, 1]],
 [[5, 1], [4, 2], [6, 3]],
 [[5, 1], [4, 3], [6, 2]],
 [[5, 1], [6, 2], [4, 3]],
 [[5, 1], [6, 3], [4, 2]],
 [[5, 2], [4, 1], [6, 3]],
 [[5, 2], [4, 3], [6, 1]],
 [[5, 2], [6, 1], [4, 3]],
 [[5, 2], [6, 3], [4, 1]],
 [[5, 3], [4, 1], [6, 2]],
 [[5, 3], [4, 2], [6, 1]],
 [[5, 3], [6, 1], [4, 2]],
 [[5, 3], [6, 2], [4, 1]],
 [[6, 1], [4, 2], [5, 3]],
...
 [[6, 2], [5, 3], [4, 1]],
 [[6, 3], [4, 1], [5, 2]],
 [[6, 3], [4, 2], [5, 1]],
 [[6, 3], [5, 1], [4, 2]],
 [[6, 3], [5, 2], [4, 1]]]
```

Comment: What is k=0 doing in your code? Also why should you pickle it? you could elaborate more. The issue in the code is not a serialization problem.